# Does executable file get created if build fails in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

Does executable file get created if Build Solution fails with some error in Visual Studio for c#?

Does Build Solution has to succeed in order to create executable file for the application in Visual Studio?

Thanks,
Ilya

Comment: Yes, the build does have succeed in order to create the executable. However, I am wondering if there is a question behind the question -- why are you asking?

Comment: Just curious because I am building a solution and wanted to know if built has to be successful in order to create .exe file

Comment: If the built is not successful, executable won’t be created, correct?

Comment: But what made you curious?

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a good question. The answer is: it depends.

There is a difference between "build" and "compile".

- The "build" does a lot of work, like finding all the source files, resolving any references to assemblies and NuGet packages, and so forth.
- The "compile" takes all those as inputs and produces an output assembly.

If the "compile" fails, then no output is produced (e.g. no `.dll` or `.exe` file).

However the "build" may fail after a successful "compile" (for example, if a post-build step fails) in which case the output file is created even though the build fails.

In 99.9999% of cases, a failed build means no output was produced, but it is not always the case.